# How to fix moderncv's ToC generation to get nesting in the PDF ToC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, hyperref, moderncv

I am preparing a (somewhat lengthly) application using the [moderncv](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) class. For this I would like to provide for some additional structure in the PDFs ToC, that is, use something like `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{<entry>}` for grouping  sections. Also I would like to have the subsections to appear nested below the sections in the PDF ToC.

However, the following fails: **All** bookmarks appear on the part-level, `\subsection` does not create a bookmark:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual}                        % style options are 'casual' (default) and 'classic' 
\moderncvcolor{blue}                          % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\phantomsection{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Academic Career}

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\subsection{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\subsection{Dissertation}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\phantomsection{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Professional Career}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\end{document}
```

[image: screen shot]

The culprit can be found in the moderncv implementation, more precisely in the definitions of the `\section` and `\subsection` commands in `moderncvstyleclassic.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{moderncvstyleclassic}[2012/01/25 v0.17 modern curriculum vitae style scheme: classic]
...
\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{%
  \vspace*{2.5ex}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#1}}%
  \par\nobreak\vskip 1ex\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading

\renewcommand*{\subsection}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintfont{} &{\subsectionstyle{#1}}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\nobreak\vskip 0.5ex\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
%  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
%  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}% does not work, the bookmark is placed at the same level as sections (placed themselves at part level to be visible, as hyperref does not allow sections without parents...)
```

The comment below the `\subsection` implementation probably explains the problem: sections are placed on part-level, subsections are not placed at all in the ToC because of issues with hyperref. I played a bit around with various `\addcontentsline`-settings, but without success.

So how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I would redefine `\section` and `\subsection` so that they use the correct levels (no idea why moderncv doesn't do this):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}                        % style options are 'casual' (default) and 'classic'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                          % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=2}}% to get sections and subsection in toc

\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{%
  \vspace*{2.5ex}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}% changed
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#1}}%
  \par\nobreak\vskip 1ex\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading

\renewcommand*{\subsection}[1]{%
  \phantomsection %added
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%added
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
      \raggedleft\hintfont{} &{\subsectionstyle{#1}}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\nobreak\vskip 0.5ex\@afterheading}

\makeatother  
\begin{document}
.......
```

Comment: This is what I have tried before asking here (and from the comments in the code I conclude that the moderncv author also did try this). The magic line in your solution both of us apparently missed is `\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=2}`. Thanks Ulrike!

Comment: I just updated `moderncv` to include this. Thanks Ulrike!

Comment: But how to get a TOC with moderncv? I get the following error if I try: ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
l.76 \tableofcontents